# Deleting a list from a list in python using list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list

I have a list as below:

```
list = [['ab_c'], ['da_c'], ['da_b']]
```

I want to delete the ['ab_c'] from list using the list comprehension. 
The resulting list will be:

```
list = [['da_c'], ['da_b']]
```

I tried using the below code:

```
new_list = [x for x in list if ['da_'] in x]
```

But the output while printing new_list is as below:

```
[]
```

It's an empty list.
Can anyone suggest me how to fulfill the above need?

Comment: 1) Don't use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) as a name. 2) What about `l = l[1:]`? 3) `'da_'` is not in `['da_c']`.

Comment: Still getting an empty list..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll interpret this as "select the sublists that have any string in them that starts with `da_`":

```
new_list = [x for x in list if any(s.startswith('da_') for s in x)]
```

Of course if there is always just a single element in the sublists, it's easier:

```
new_list = [x for x in list if x[0].startswith('da_')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = [x for x in l if 'da_' in x[0]]
```

Output:

```
[['da_c'], ['da_b']]
```

Comment: where `l =[['ab_c'], ['da_c'], ['da_b']]`

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
lis= [['ab_c'], ['da_c'], ['da_b']]
new_list = [x for x in lis if any(s.startswith('da_') for s in x)]
print new_list
```

output:

```
[['da_c'], ['da_b']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list = [['ab_c'], ['da_c'], ['da_b']]
new_list = []
for item in list:
  if 'ab_c' not in item:
    new_list.append(item)

print new_list
```